# Bash - how to find and remove all files that contain a given string?

Tags: design-patterns, grep, find, xargs

Let's say there's a number of files in a given directory with various file extensions or no extensions at all, just filename. Some of these files include the string "**`\/for\/endetta`**".

How do I find and remove all the files in that directory matching this pattern? I could do sort of do this by using:

```
find -type f -exec egrep -Il '\/for\/endetta' {} \;|xargs rm -fv
```

1. But is it possible to do it without xargs?
2. And how do I properly escape the \s and /s, etc.

Comment: Something like `find -type f -exec grep -q '\/for\/endetta' {} \; -delete` SHOULD work (since -exec will take exit status of command it runs), but I don't have the time to check it at the moment. Replace `-delete` with `-print` to check.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying. Sadly it didn't work. The command appears to execute (didn't throw any errors) but it didn't delete any of the files that have the specified string in them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BrowSlow's answer (in the comments) is correct, except for the escape of the /for/endetta.
Try this command:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q '\\/for\\/endetta' {} \; -delete
```

If the exit status of grep is true, the following action is executed. Replace -delete with -print to see which files would be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Use recursive grep to find all the files, then delete them. Like that:

```
for file in $( fgrep -l -r '\/for\/endetta' ../ ); do rm "$file"; done
```

With fgrep and single quotes you do not need to escape anything.